# How to solve a linear transform given part of the input and output vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Lets say $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $v = A w$, where $A \in M_{n \times n}$. We are given all entries of $A$.

Now, If I am given all the components of $w$ it is very easy to find $v$, and if I am given $v$ I can find $w$ by inverting $A$.

The question is if I am given $m$ components of $v$ and $l$ components of $w$, how can I find $v,w$ ?

---

I know this cannot be done for all possible inputs, but I want an algorithmic solution method similar to finding the inverse of a matrix.

So far, I would solve problems like this by converting to systems of equations and then solving them in a case by case basis.

---

I would like to be able to do this with linear algebra, or tensors.

*Note, when I say components, I refer to the standard basis coordinates.

Comment: how is this question related to Wolfram Language/Mathematica? is there any relevant code you are having trouble with and would benefit from other users' insights? have you looked at the documentation center for relevant functions eg [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) or [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve)?

Comment: Shoot, this probably should've been on math stack exchange. Is there some way to migrate my question there? @user42582